Sorting between two years
My first error with this query was the year, and I fixed that by only adding quotation at the beggining and end of the years.  That gave me a different syntax error with the ORDER BY.  Any suggestions? this is a school project.
AND Year  BETWEEN '2016 AND 2018'
ORDER BY
Births
DESC;

I would have expected it to be AND Year BETWEEN '2016' AND '2018' with quotes around each value unless year is actually numeric in which case it should be AND Year BETWEEN 2016 AND 2018 without quotes at all.

I tried both, and I got the same error:  AND Year BETWEEN '2016-01-01 AND 2018-12-31'
ORDER BY
Births
DESC;

WHERE
County_of_Residence = 'Erie County, NY'
OR County_of_Residence = 'Niagara County, NY'
OR County_of_Residence = 'Chautaugua County, NY'
AND Year BETWEEN '2016-01-01 AND 2018-12-31'
ORDER BY
Births
DESC;

Can you edit your question to include the variations you've tried and the errors  you're getting.

Your answer worked, I changed it to quotation on both sides, and I received good results.  Thank you.

AND Year BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2018-12-31'
ORDER BY
Births
DESC;

Thank you for reaching out.  This was solved with the suggestion posted.
